# how to increase rows size in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How to increase rows size in DataGridView using C#? I can't find this property .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for the number of rows or the height of each row perhaps?

Comment: Increase the size how - height?  Width?  Are you wanting to set this in the markup, or do it in the codebehind, or dynamically in response to an event or somet other input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always loop through all `DataGridViewRow`s and set the `Height` property:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    if (heightShouldBeSet) {
        row.Height = yourHeightSetting;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gali Only through the DataGridView's DataGridViewRowCollection like I showed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new Row.

```
int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = title;
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dateTimeNow;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the row height you can also just contatenate empty line to the cell value.