# fit dataGridView size to row's and columns's total size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make a dataGridView's size to fit the columns and rows total size. About total height, I managed to fit it to columns's height like that:

```
const int datagridLines = 30;
s.Height = dataGridView2.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Size.Height;
for (byte i = 0; i < datagridLines; i++)
{
  dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
  s.Height += dataGridView2.Rows[i].Height;
}
dataGridView2.ClientSize = s;
```

I tried some things to also fit the width but no luck. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work:

```
int height = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    height += row.Height;
}
height += dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;

int width = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns) {
    width += col.Width;
}
width += dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth;

dataGridView1.ClientSize = new Size(width + 2, height + 2);
```

The + 2 to the `width` and `height` values are a fudge factor to account for the width of the DataGridView's interior elements.  I recall seeing code somewhere that will allow you to get this value without the hard coded numbers but I can't find it now.

Comment: Could it be the Padding property contributes to the +2 offset values? See accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193268/how-to-decrese-the-size-of-button-to-a-small-size-inside-cell-of-datagrid-view-bu/7198229#comment-8785853.

Comment: @TheBlastOne - The Padding property sets the space between the cell edge and it's content.  I believe the DataGridViewColumn.DividerWidth property has something to do with it.

Comment: Instead of doing the calculations yourself, I'd look at ticcky's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12455252/467172.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

GetRowsHeight and GetColumnsWidth methods of Rows and Columns collections should give you what you need in an effortless way:

```
var totalHeight = dataGridView2.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.None);
var totalWidth = dataGridView2.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.None);
```

Comment: This does not include header height/width.

Comment: you can do totalwidth+=dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth;

Answer (score 7):

A bit more complete version:

```
dataGridView.Height = dataGridView.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.None) + dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight + 2;

dataGridView.Width = dataGridView.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.None) + dataGridView.RowHeadersWidth + 2;
```

Comment: worth noting, that combines the best of ticcky and jay, but you should elaborate on the '2'.

Comment: doesn't work for this case, though I have an inefficient method that works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635932/calculate-padding-of-datagridview-when-padding-is-greater-than-two

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the properties of the DataGridViewRow collection and DataGridViewColumn collection to do this.

Try the approach similar to the one used in this:

[how to increase rows size in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586685/how-to-increase-rows-size-in-datagridview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer too Mamta Dalal.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tad late and in visual basic, but this worked for me in case
someone else finds this thread.  I'm using a docked datagridview in a tableLayoutPanel, which automatically resizes when the form is resized.  It doesn't shrink the form.  I just start the form small.  Rows could be added using the same technique.

```
Private Sub setFormWidth()
        Dim iTotalWidth As Integer = 0 '884
        Dim iDisplayedWidth As Integer = 0
        Dim r As Rectangle
        For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In dgv_EmpList.Columns
            If c.Visible Then
                iTotalWidth += c.Width
                r = dgv_EmpList.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(c.Index, True)
                iDisplayedWidth += r.Width
            End If
        Next
        Me.Width += (iTotalWidth - iDisplayedWidth)
    End Sub
```

Comment: A block quote is for when you are quoting another source.  Also, unless your form is borderless, you should use Me.ClientSize instead, since that would exclude borders (which have different values on different Window versions).