# Create a gridview event who select some elements of the same columns

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I've got a gridview with some cells from a database. The user should only be able to select the rows of 1 column at a time. Example :

```
   0   1   2  
0  a   b   c      
1  d   e   f     
2  g   h   i
```

If the user drags the mouse (while pressing the left button) from 0/0 = a to 1/1 = e
only the cells a and d should be selected. (Multi column selection shouldn't be allowed)

If someone can help,

Thank you

That's what I got for the beginning :

```
private void myDataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {

            var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            coord[0] = hti.RowIndex;
            coord[1] = hti.ColumnIndex;
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            coord[2] = hti.RowIndex;
            coord[3] = hti.ColumnIndex;

            // Some actions 
}
```

This example still selects multiple columns.

Comment: Ok you want to select cells that are in the same row. But how do you determine which rows of which column should be selected. What event do you use?

Comment: Ok your english is a bit cryptic to me so what do you want exactly. Select only the elements of one column even though the user selected multiple columns.

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad, i've got a lot of problems to speak, but it's ok to understand you. 
But yes, it's that. If the user begin to select in column 'A', he can't select multi columns, only rows in column 'A'.

Comment: Ok I got you now. I'll correct your question and gonna give you an answer tomorrow. Because i am running out of time. But that shouldn't be a problem ;)

Comment: This question is still without answer.

Comment: Sorry was ill and then traveling around. But I ll try to find some time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace gridview
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool buttonIsPressed = false;
        int rowIndex, columnIndex;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            completeDataGridview();
        }

        //this function only creates a filled DataGridView
        private void completeDataGridview()
        {
            dataGridView1.RowCount = 3;
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value = ((char)(97 + y + 3 * x)).ToString();
                }
            }

            // this part is stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412098/fit-datagridview-size-to-rows-and-columnss-total-size
            int height = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                height += row.Height;
            }
            height += dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;

            int width = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                width += col.Width;
            }
            width += dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth;

            dataGridView1.ClientSize = new Size(width + 2, height);

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            buttonIsPressed = true;
            rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
            columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;            
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (buttonIsPressed)
            {
                int startingRow = 0;
                if (rowIndex > e.RowIndex)
                    startingRow = e.RowIndex;
                else
                    startingRow = rowIndex;

                //at first we have to deselect every cell
                deselectEveryCell();

                //then reselect the old ones
                int amountOfRows = Math.Abs(rowIndex - e.RowIndex) + 1;
                for (int x = 0; x < amountOfRows; x++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[startingRow + x].Cells[columnIndex].Selected = true;
                }
            }
            buttonIsPressed = false;
        }

        private void deselectEveryCell()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.RowCount; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; y++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Selected = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (buttonIsPressed)
                deselectEveryCell();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code you need.
the function `completeDataGridview()` isn't important.

You need 3 events. `CellMouseDown`, `CellMouseUp` and `MouseLeave`.

In `CellMouseDown` we get the info of the initial selected Cell and save it in rowindex and columnindex. And buttonPressed is set to true (this could be helpful later on).

If the mousebutton is released while the mousepointer points at a cell the event `CellMouseUp` is fired. We first check which cell is nearer to the top of the DGV (the cell at the beginning or the current one).
Then every cell is deselected.
Afterwards we check the amount of cells we did select (which is stored in `amountOfRows`).
Then we select the "correct" cells again.

The event `MouseLeave` could be important too. Otherwise the user can "abuse" ur functionality by starting to select one cell and dragging the mouse out of the DGV. Without the function he would be able to select multiple columns.

If you still got any questions don't hesitate to ask.