# datagridview data displayed in smaller area as the size of datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using a datagridview with all default properties and on form load event writing below code

```
myDatagridview.datasource=myDataTable;
```

When the form is loaded, the data displayed is not covering the size of the datagridview and in rest of the area grey screen is displayed.

I want that data to be displayed completely in the control area.

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412098/fit-datagridview-size-to-rows-and-columnss-total-size, it might help you

Comment: This will resize my control as per data but I want the data columns to get resized to control width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the AutoSizeMode property of last column to Fill

```
dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```